# Ember - No Data in hasMany Relationship On Initial Load

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

ember-cli - 3.20, ember-data - 3.30

I am trying to modify the data in a hasMany relationship in the controller setup but the relationship has no data.  However, all the data is there after the page is fully loaded (i.e. in my template/actions, all relationship data is there)

I have a Quiz application with Many-Many relationship with Questions.

**models/Quiz.js**

```
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
import DS from 'ember-data';

const { attr, hasMany, Model } = DS;

export default Model.extend({
  description: attr('string'),
  questions: hasMany('question', {async: true}) //also tried with async false

});
```

**models/Question.js**

```
export default Model.extend({
  question: attr('string'),
  quizzes: hasMany('quiz', {async: true}) //also tried with async false
});
```

Go to url '/quiz/1' and Route calls findRecord on quiz

**routes/quizzes/quiz.js**

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  model(params) { return this.store.findRecord('quiz', params.quiz_id); }
});
```

**controllers/quizzes/quiz.js**

```
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({
  quiz: computed.alias('model'),

  //also attempted in setupController/afterModel in router
  modelChanged: function() {
    let quiz = this.get('quiz');
    let questions = quiz.get('questions'); //questions has no data
    questions.then(questions => {
      Promise.all(questions.map(question => {
        //modify questions/answers here
      }));
    });
  }.observes('model')

actions: {
  getQuestions() {
    let questions = this.get('quiz.questions');  //questions now has data
  }
})};
```

I have tried to get the question data in both setupController() and afterModel() with no luck.

Note:
The quizzes are nested routes able to select between each quiz to display.  So if you navigate from '/quiz/1' to '/quiz/2' and then back to 'quiz/1', the question data is available in the observer, setupController, afterModel, etc.  So, the second time you access a specific quiz, the data is available in setup.  (*data is always available in template/actions*).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Temporary Workaround:

Use an observer on 'quiz.questions' along with a flag to check if first time hitting observer.

```
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({
  quiz: computed.alias('model'),

  areAnswersSet: false,

  observeQuestions: function() {
    let questions = this.get('quiz.questions');
    if (!this.areAnswersSet && questions.length !== 0) {
      this.toggleProperty('areAnswersSet');
      questions.forEach(question => { //modify question });
    }
  }.observes('quiz.questions.[]')
```

**Drawback**: Observer will still get called on every questions change.  Only needed on initial load.

Comment: As the questions relationship is async, you maybe could also observe `quiz.questions.isFulfilled`, to only run once per load (may need to observe as `quiz.{questions,questions.isFulfilled}` to recognize change to a different model.questions). Or dynamically add the observer for `quiz.questions.[]` on model change and remove it once fired. See [addObserver](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.2/classes/EmberObject/methods/addObserver?anchor=addObserver)/[removeObserver](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.2/classes/EmberObject/methods/removeObserver?anchor=removeObserver).

Answer (score 0):

There were a few bugs in Ember Data 3.3.0 that were related to relationships. It’s worth upgrading to Ember Data 3.3.1 to see if your issue goes away ...